# First Fragment onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back, onbackpressed

So..
I have got multiple Fragments, the first one the user gets to see after login is considered as 'WelcomeFragment' and the rest does not matter.

I want to pop up a dialog for the logout procedure ONLY when the user is looking at the WelcomeFragment. How can I achieve this? I tried following:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Logout")
                        .setMessage("Sure you want to logout?")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                tool.logout();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(R.mipmap.change)
                        .show();


            }
            else {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }


        }
    }
```

(The logout method)

```
public void logout() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mainIntent.putExtra("logout", "logout");
    context.startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fr = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WelcomeFragmentTag");
if (null != fr && fr.isAdded()) {
    // show dialog
} else {
    // do not show dialog
}
```

This assumes, that you have added your `WelcomeFragment` providing `WelcomeFragmentTag` as a transaction tag:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content_frame,  new WelcomeFragment(), "WelcomeFragmentTag")
        .commit();
```

Comment: When the user gets on the fragment due to backpress from another fragment, will the WelcomeFragment keep the tag?

Comment: The problem is now that I cannot go back from the other fragments to WelcomeFragment by clicking on the Back button.

Comment: Also I have a strange problem, when I now click on the nav bar and go manually to WelcomeFragment the textView gets darker and the fragment is like fixed, when I try getting on antother fragment, the WelcomeFragment View is still there but fused or mixed with the other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) Do not add WelcomeFragment to backstack and only verify this onBackPressed function:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
    //Logout dialog
}
```

2) Add WelcomeFragment with a TAG and verify if that TAG is the one on top, onBackPressed function:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
cont = fm.getBackStackEntryCount()
if(cont>0&&fm.getBackStackEntryAt(cont-1).getName().equals("WelcomeFragmentTAG"){
    //Logout dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove all the fragment but Welcome Fragment-
As Welcome fragment is first fragment-

```
 FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
 for(int i=1; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++)
    {
       fm.popBackStack();
    }
```

Then check for current fragment is welcome fragment

```
 Fragment fr = fm.findFragmentByTag("WelcomeFragmentTag");
    if (null != fr && fr.isAdded()) {
        // show dialog
    } else {
        // do not show dialog
    }
```